# Testing multiple browsers with a single test definition in Selenium

Tags: python, selenium

Is there an easy way to do this in Python? I have a pytest funcarg defined like so;

```
def pytest_funcarg__selenium(request):
    sel = selenium('10.3.10.154', 5555, '*firefox', 'http://10.3.10.180:8000')
    sel.start()

    return sel
```

Which obviously won't work, as I have no means of changing the specified browser in my tests. I mean, I could wrap a dummy class around selenium in this funcarg that loops through a list of browsers, but if a test fails, then it will fail for all browsers, which of course isn't very practical for finding failing browsers.

I also played with the idea of using a decorator on the test function, which would redefine the function once in the module for each browser under a different name, but same result - the funcarg has no way of knowing which browser to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One technique I've seen used is to organize the tests in a class and use subclassing to switch class variables indicating which browser to test:

```
class TestFirefox:
    browser = '*firefox'

    def pytest_funcarg__selenium(self, request):
        sel = selenium('10.3.10.154', 5555, self.browser, 'http://10.3.10.180:8000')
        sel.start()
        return sel 

class TestChrome(TestFirefox):
    browser = '*opera'
```

Besides maximizing code reuse, this technique also lets you override and custom selected tests for various browsers.

In py.test, I believe you can use [generative tests](http://pytest.org/latest/example/parametrize.html#generating-parameters-combinations-depending-on-command-line) to the same effect.

Comment: This is looking like the best solution so far. Also, I didn't know you could define funcargs as class level methods, which is cool.

Answer (score 0):

By using selenium Grid you can run single test in multiple browsers. Is it what you intended to?

Comment: What do I specify in the browser string for this to work, then?

Comment: W.r.t selenium grid, in testng.xml file specify the browser string as <parameter name="selenium.browser" value="*firefox"/>

Comment: I fail to see how that's going to automatically run one test in every browser. There's no browser string for 'all nodes'.

Answer (score 0):

Use an environment variable to supply the browser string, and default it to something useful (*e.g.*, `*firefox`) if not supplied.  Then you can simply set the value before running the test class from the command line.

Comment: This would be a great solution, except that our automated test system is a little odd, so something like this would be quite difficult. With a better testing system, I'd like this approach.